# При скролле один блок перекрывает другой

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте, у меня есть `html` код:

```html
<header class="main-header">
  ........
</header>

<section class="main-preview">
  .....
</section>

<section class="about">
  ......
</section>

Следущие блоки
```

Мне необходимо, чтобы `.main-header` с `.main-preview` были статичны и при скролле страницы перекрывались блоком `.about` и остальными блоками.

То есть мы скроллим и на место `.main-header` и `.main-preview`, встает остальная часть сайта и скроллится уже в обычном режиме. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать, а то даже не знаю как загуглить.

Я предполагаю, что можно засунуть `.main-header` и `.main-preview` в один блок, дать ему `position:fixed` и тогда будет что-то похожее, но при `position:fixed` остальные блоки становятся поверх фиксированного и весь план ломается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял задачу, то вот таким образом

```css
.main {
  position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
  .main_header {
    height: 50px; width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
  }
  .main_preview {
    height: 50px; width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
  }
  
.about {
  position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 120vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <header class="main_header">
  </header>
  <section class="main_preview">
  </section>
</div>
<section class="about">
</section>
```

Регулировать какой блок будет поверх какого можно с помощью `z-index`

**UPDATA:**

Если у вас размеры этих двух блоков не изменяются, то можно сделать следующим образом

```css
body {margin: 0;}

.main {
  position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
  .main_header {
    height: 50px; width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
  }
  .main_preview {
    height: 50px; width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
  }
  
.about {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; height: 120vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <header class="main_header">
  </header>
  <section class="main_preview">
  </section>
</div>
<section class="about">
</section>
```

Или со скриптом:

```js
var el__about = document.querySelector('.about'),
    el__main = document.querySelector('.main');
    
el__about.style.marginTop = el__main.getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px';
```

```css
body {margin: 0;}

.main {
  position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
  .main_header {
    height: 50px; width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
  }
  .main_preview {
    height: 50px; width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
  }
  
.about {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; height: 120vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <header class="main_header">
  </header>
  <section class="main_preview">
  </section>
</div>
<section class="about">
</section>
```

Comment: Скорее всего это оно, я себе это примерно так и представлял, просто думал есть какое-то решение при котором эти два блока не залазили бы друг на друга
То есть чтобы блоку .about не выставлять значение top
В принципе сейчас поиграюсь со стилями чтобы сайт выглядел как надо
Спасибо

Comment: @nazarukroman, если у вас у двух блоков всегда один и тот же размер, то я могу показать, как сделать без top

Comment: страница нужна адаптивная, поэтому и думаю как быть с блоками)

Comment: @nazarukroman, добавил обновление в вопрос. По другому не знаю, как осуществить нормально

Comment: спасибо, попробую еще один ваш вариант
Пока что сделал блоку .about top: 100% и как раз у меня получается первый блок во весь экран как первая страница